# Google App Engine dev_appserver.py IOError when importing apache_beam

Tags: python, google-app-engine, apache-beam

I have an App Engine application which breaks the moment I do

```
import apache_beam
```

I can confirm the dependencies are installed within the virtual environment the app runs in. Judging by the stack trace below it looks like it's trying to access /dev/null for some reason and it fails to.

```
INFO     2017-08-13 13:03:37,980 stubs.py:50] Sandbox prevented access to file "/home/raul/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk"
INFO     2017-08-13 13:03:37,980 stubs.py:51] If it is a static file, check that `application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml
INFO     2017-08-13 13:03:37,980 stubs.py:50] Sandbox prevented access to file "/home/raul/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform"
INFO     2017-08-13 13:03:37,980 stubs.py:51] If it is a static file, check that `application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml
INFO     2017-08-13 13:03:38,260 stubs.py:50] Sandbox prevented access to file "/dev/null"
INFO     2017-08-13 13:03:38,260 stubs.py:51] If it is a static file, check that `application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml
ERROR    2017-08-13 13:03:38,261 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raul/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/raul/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/raul/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/raul/Documents/football/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import apache_beam
  File "/home/raul/Documents/football/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    import apache_beam.internal.pickler
  File "/home/raul/Documents/football/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 38, in <module>
    import dill
  File "/home/raul/Documents/football/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .dill import dump, dumps, load, loads, dump_session, load_session, \
  File "/home/raul/Documents/football/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 165, in <module>
    FileType = type(open(os.devnull, 'rb', buffering=0))
  File "/home/raul/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py", line 260, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/dev/null'
```

Any ideas what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: did you deploy it on google cloud or local environment? Reason being, I am also trying add a cron to run dataflow pipes through appengine and it would help me. :)

Comment: I did not get to deploy it since I couldn't get it to run on the development server in the first place because of the sandbox restrictions. The flexible environment seems to be the way to go for that kind of use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GAE [Python sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_The_sandbox) is pretty restrictive in terms of what your app code is allowed to do. It looks like the `dill` package used by `apache-beam` needs to access special files (the `/dev/null` device file in this case) which is not allowed on the sandbox.

You either change your code to meet all sandbox requirements or try to use [the flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/), which is a lot more tolerant (but it's a different beast overall). See [Choosing an App Engine Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) and  [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating).

Side note: the traceback indicates your app tried to execute apache-beam from the local system installation, which also won't work in the standard environment - it needs to be vendored into your application, see [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library).